# Measuring a part of the page

Tags: boxes

I'm trying to measure the height of a part of my page.

The complete titlepage, along with the part of the page I'm trying to measure is outlined in red, and the code to compile the page is shown below that. Yes, I have to measure it all at once. `:-(`

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kXhDH.png]

```
\documentclass[10pt]{extarticle}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=.9in]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{palette2}{RGB}{235,249,249}
\usepackage[letterspace=400]{microtype}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[bitstream-charter]{mathdesign}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newcommand{\headrulecolor}[1]{\patchcmd{\headrule}{\hrule}{\color{#1}\hrule}{}{}}
\makeatletter
\fancypagestyle{plain}{
  \fancyhf{}
  \headrulecolor{lightgray}
  \chead{\textit{Some science institution}}
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{.5pt}
}
\setlength\parindent\z@
\newcommand*\docparspacing{
\setlength\parindent{16pt}
\setlength\parskip{0pt}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{plain}

\raisebox{3.5ex}{\hbadness=9999
\colorbox{palette2}{\vrule width 0pt height 5.8ex \begin{tabular}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}p{\dimexpr.3\linewidth-\tabcolsep} >{\centering\arraybackslash}p{\dimexpr.35\linewidth-2\tabcolsep} >{\RaggedLeft\arraybackslash}p{\dimexpr.35\linewidth-4.4\tabcolsep}}
&
&
\end{tabular}}}
\vskip 2ex
\textcolor{lightgray}{\hrule height .5pt}
\vskip 6ex
\Huge{A title in fontsize Huge}
\vskip .4ex
\large{Doe, J. (John)}
\vskip 2ex
\normalsize
\vskip .5ex
\valign{%
    \hsize=\dimexpr.5\linewidth-2\tabcolsep
    \vskip 2ex
    #\vfil\nointerlineskip
    \vskip 1.5ex
    \cr
    \noindent\textls{\itshape\footnotesize KEYWORDS}
    \vskip -1.5ex
    \hbox to\hsize{\color{lightgray}\leaders\hrule height .5pt\hfill}
    \vskip 1.5ex
    \itshape{obituary

    linguist

    typography}\cr
    \noalign{\hfill}
    \noindent\textls{\itshape\footnotesize ABSTRACT}
    \vskip -1.5ex
    \hbox to\hsize{\color{lightgray}\leaders\hrule height .5pt\hfill}
    \vskip 1.5ex

    \small \lipsum[4] \cr
  }\par
  \vskip2ex

  \hbox to\linewidth{\color{lightgray}\leaders\hrule height .5pt\hfill}
\vskip 3ex

\colorbox{palette2}{%
\begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\fboxsep}
\lipsum[1-2]
\end{minipage}%
}
\vskip 5ex
\docparspacing
\begin{multicols*}{3}
\section{Document structure}
\lipsum[1-3]
\end{multicols*}
\end{document}
```

I tried measuring this by creating my own box, which compiles with eight errors and requires extensive use of `\hbox` and `\vbox`. It also required me to replace every instance of `\hrule` with a `\leaders` variant, which requires glue (the bane of my existence). I strongly suspect this to be the culprit of the incorrect output. However, my main question is, my current approach seems particularly cumbersome, which leads me to believe my approach is not the right one, i.e. an approach more flexible (or "easy" if you wish) exists. How can I create this box for measurement and usage in the document, in the most accessible/flexible manner?

[image: http://i.imgur.com/o89CdlS.png?1]

```
\documentclass[10pt]{extarticle}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=.9in]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{palette2}{RGB}{235,249,249}
\usepackage[letterspace=400]{microtype}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[bitstream-charter]{mathdesign}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newcommand{\headrulecolor}[1]{\patchcmd{\headrule}{\hrule}{\color{#1}\hrule}{}{}}
\makeatletter
\fancypagestyle{plain}{
  \fancyhf{}
  \headrulecolor{lightgray}
  \chead{\textit{Some science institution}}
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{.5pt}
}
\setlength\parindent\z@
\newcommand*\docparspacing{
\setlength\parindent{16pt}
\setlength\parskip{0pt}
}
\makeatother

\newsavebox\titlebox
\setbox\titlebox=\vbox{%
\hbox{\raisebox{3.5ex}{\hbadness=9999
\colorbox{palette2}{\vrule width 0pt height 5.8ex \begin{tabular}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}p{\dimexpr.3\linewidth-\tabcolsep} >{\centering\arraybackslash}p{\dimexpr.35\linewidth-2\tabcolsep} >{\RaggedLeft\arraybackslash}p{\dimexpr.35\linewidth-4.4\tabcolsep}}
&
&
\end{tabular}}}
}
\vskip 2ex
\hbox to \linewidth{\textcolor{lightgray}{\leaders\hrule height .5pt\hfil}}
\vskip 6ex
\hbox{\Huge{A title in fontsize Huge}}
\vskip .4ex
\hbox{\large{Doe, J. (John)}}
\vskip 2ex
\normalsize
\vskip .5ex
\valign{%
    \hsize=\dimexpr.5\linewidth-2\tabcolsep
    \vskip 2ex
    #\vfil\nointerlineskip
    \vskip 1.5ex
    \cr
    \noindent\textls{\itshape\footnotesize KEYWORDS}
    \vskip -1.5ex
    \hbox to\hsize{\color{lightgray}\leaders\hrule height .5pt\hfil}
    \vskip 1.5ex
    \itshape{obituary

    linguist

    typography}\cr
    \noalign{\hfill}
    \noindent\textls{\itshape\footnotesize ABSTRACT}
    \vskip -1.5ex
    \hbox to\hsize{\color{lightgray}\leaders\hrule height .5pt\hfil}
    \vskip 1.5ex

    \small \lipsum[4] \cr
  }\par
\vskip2ex
\hbox to\linewidth{\color{lightgray}\leaders\hrule height .5pt\hfil}
\vskip 3ex
\colorbox{palette2}{%
\begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\fboxsep}
  \lipsum[1-2]
\end{minipage}%
}
\vskip 5ex
}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{plain}

\usebox\titlebox
\docparspacing
\begin{multicols*}{3}
\section{Document structure}
\lipsum[1-3]
\end{multicols*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\the\ht\titlebox` tells how tall is your box. `\tracingpages1` may also help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may use the `tcolorbox` package (version `3.12 (2014/07/29)` or newer) to do the measuring. In my solution, the kernel is an environment `measurebox` constructed by the following code:

```
\makeatletter
\newtcolorbox{measurebox}[1][]{blank,parbox=false,
  show bounding box,
  finish={\node[draw,fill=white,fill opacity=0.85,inner sep=5mm,
    rounded corners,align=left,node font=\Large\bfseries]
    at (frame.center) { width: \tcb@width,\\ height: \tcb@height};},
  #1}
\makeatother
```

Any paragraph encircled by this environment `tcolorbox` is measured and its dimension is written on the screen or paper. The complete code is:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{extarticle}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=.9in]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{palette2}{RGB}{235,249,249}
\usepackage[letterspace=400]{microtype}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[bitstream-charter]{mathdesign}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}% version `3.12 (2014/07/29)` or newer

\makeatletter% construct boxing environment
\newtcolorbox{measurebox}[1][]{blank,parbox=false,
  show bounding box,
  finish={\node[draw,fill=white,fill opacity=0.85,inner sep=5mm,
    rounded corners,align=left,node font=\Large\bfseries]
    at (frame.center) { width: \tcb@width,\\ height: \tcb@height};},
  #1}
\makeatother% end construction

\newcommand{\headrulecolor}[1]{\patchcmd{\headrule}{\hrule}{\color{#1}\hrule}{}{}}
\makeatletter
\fancypagestyle{plain}{
  \fancyhf{}
  \headrulecolor{lightgray}
  \chead{\textit{Some science institution}}
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{.5pt}
}
\setlength\parindent\z@
\newcommand*\docparspacing{
\setlength\parindent{16pt}
\setlength\parskip{0pt}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{plain}

\begin{measurebox}%----- start measuring -----
\raisebox{3.5ex}{\hbadness=9999
\colorbox{palette2}{\vrule width 0pt height 5.8ex \begin{tabular}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}p{\dimexpr.3\linewidth-\tabcolsep} >{\centering\arraybackslash}p{\dimexpr.35\linewidth-2\tabcolsep} >{\RaggedLeft\arraybackslash}p{\dimexpr.35\linewidth-4.4\tabcolsep}}
&
&
\end{tabular}}}
\vskip 2ex
\textcolor{lightgray}{\hrule height .5pt}
\vskip 6ex
\Huge{A title in fontsize Huge}
\vskip .4ex
\large{Doe, J. (John)}
\vskip 2ex
\normalsize
\vskip .5ex
\valign{%
    \hsize=\dimexpr.5\linewidth-2\tabcolsep
    \vskip 2ex
    #\vfil\nointerlineskip
    \vskip 1.5ex
    \cr
    \noindent\textls{\itshape\footnotesize KEYWORDS}
    \vskip -1.5ex
    \hbox to\hsize{\color{lightgray}\leaders\hrule height .5pt\hfill}
    \vskip 1.5ex
    \itshape{obituary

    linguist

    typography}\cr
    \noalign{\hfill}
    \noindent\textls{\itshape\footnotesize ABSTRACT}
    \vskip -1.5ex
    \hbox to\hsize{\color{lightgray}\leaders\hrule height .5pt\hfill}
    \vskip 1.5ex

    \small \lipsum[4] \cr
  }\par
  \vskip2ex

  \hbox to\linewidth{\color{lightgray}\leaders\hrule height .5pt\hfill}
\vskip 3ex

\colorbox{palette2}{%
\begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\fboxsep}
\lipsum[1-2]
\end{minipage}%
}
\vskip 5ex
\end{measurebox}%----- end measuring -----
\docparspacing
\begin{multicols*}{3}
\section{Document structure}
\lipsum[1-3]
\end{multicols*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The environment `measurebox` takes an optional argument which can be used to influence the box. In this application, it may be useful to change the spacing before or after the box, e.g. by

```
\begin{measurebox}[before=\par\bigskip,
                   after=\par\vskip 10ex]
...
```

**Second Solution:**

This is a variant of the first part. Now, the height of the box is saved into a mandatory parameter of `measurebox` for further usage:

```
\makeatletter
\newtcolorbox{measurebox}[2][]{blank,parbox=false,
  overlay={\xdef#2{\tcb@height}},
  #1}
\makeatother
```

It is used like the following:

```
\begin{measurebox}{\myheight}
```

All together, this is:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{extarticle}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=.9in]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{palette2}{RGB}{235,249,249}
\usepackage[letterspace=400]{microtype}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[bitstream-charter]{mathdesign}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}

\makeatletter
\newtcolorbox{measurebox}[2][]{blank,parbox=false,
  overlay={\xdef#2{\tcb@height}},
  #1}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\headrulecolor}[1]{\patchcmd{\headrule}{\hrule}{\color{#1}\hrule}{}{}}
\makeatletter
\fancypagestyle{plain}{
  \fancyhf{}
  \headrulecolor{lightgray}
  \chead{\textit{Some science institution}}
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{.5pt}
}
\setlength\parindent\z@
\newcommand*\docparspacing{
\setlength\parindent{16pt}
\setlength\parskip{0pt}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{plain}

\begin{measurebox}{\myheight}
\raisebox{3.5ex}{\hbadness=9999
\colorbox{palette2}{\vrule width 0pt height 5.8ex \begin{tabular}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}p{\dimexpr.3\linewidth-\tabcolsep} >{\centering\arraybackslash}p{\dimexpr.35\linewidth-2\tabcolsep} >{\RaggedLeft\arraybackslash}p{\dimexpr.35\linewidth-4.4\tabcolsep}}
&
&
\end{tabular}}}
\vskip 2ex
\textcolor{lightgray}{\hrule height .5pt}
\vskip 6ex
\Huge{A title in fontsize Huge}
\vskip .4ex
\large{Doe, J. (John)}
\vskip 2ex
\normalsize
\vskip .5ex
\valign{%
    \hsize=\dimexpr.5\linewidth-2\tabcolsep
    \vskip 2ex
    #\vfil\nointerlineskip
    \vskip 1.5ex
    \cr
    \noindent\textls{\itshape\footnotesize KEYWORDS}
    \vskip -1.5ex
    \hbox to\hsize{\color{lightgray}\leaders\hrule height .5pt\hfill}
    \vskip 1.5ex
    \itshape{obituary

    linguist

    typography}\cr
    \noalign{\hfill}
    \noindent\textls{\itshape\footnotesize ABSTRACT}
    \vskip -1.5ex
    \hbox to\hsize{\color{lightgray}\leaders\hrule height .5pt\hfill}
    \vskip 1.5ex

    \small \lipsum[4] \cr
  }\par
  \vskip2ex

  \hbox to\linewidth{\color{lightgray}\leaders\hrule height .5pt\hfill}
\vskip 3ex

\colorbox{palette2}{%
\begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\fboxsep}
\lipsum[1-2]
\end{minipage}%
}
\vskip 5ex
\end{measurebox}
\docparspacing
\begin{multicols*}{3}
\section{Document structure}
\textcolor{red}{The box above has a height of \myheight.}\par
\lipsum[1-3]
\end{multicols*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Third Solution:**

The third solution omits `tcolorbox` completely. A macro `\measurebox` is created by

```
\newcommand{\measurebox}[4]{%
  \sbox{#1}{\begin{minipage}{#2}#4%
  \end{minipage}}%
  \edef#3{\the\dimexpr\ht#1+\dp#1\relax}%
}
```

It takes four parameters: `#1` is a valid boxname, `#2` is a width, `#3` is a macro name with will get the total height of the box, `#4` is the box content. It is used like the following:

```
\newsavebox\titlebox
\measurebox{\titlebox}{\textwidth}{\myheight}{%----- start measuring
...
}%----- end measuring
%
\usebox\titlebox%  somewhere
The box above has a height of \myheight.% somewhere
```

The complete code with the same output as above is:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{extarticle}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=.9in]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{palette2}{RGB}{235,249,249}
\usepackage[letterspace=400]{microtype}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[bitstream-charter]{mathdesign}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\measurebox}[4]{%
  \sbox{#1}{\begin{minipage}{#2}#4%
  \end{minipage}}%
  \edef#3{\the\dimexpr\ht#1+\dp#1\relax}%
}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\headrulecolor}[1]{\patchcmd{\headrule}{\hrule}{\color{#1}\hrule}{}{}}
\makeatletter
\fancypagestyle{plain}{
  \fancyhf{}
  \headrulecolor{lightgray}
  \chead{\textit{Some science institution}}
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{.5pt}
}
\setlength\parindent\z@
\newcommand*\docparspacing{
\setlength\parindent{16pt}
\setlength\parskip{0pt}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{plain}

\newsavebox\titlebox
\measurebox{\titlebox}{\textwidth}{\myheight}{%----- start measuring
\raisebox{3.5ex}{\hbadness=9999
\colorbox{palette2}{\vrule width 0pt height 5.8ex \begin{tabular}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}p{\dimexpr.3\linewidth-\tabcolsep} >{\centering\arraybackslash}p{\dimexpr.35\linewidth-2\tabcolsep} >{\RaggedLeft\arraybackslash}p{\dimexpr.35\linewidth-4.4\tabcolsep}}
&
&
\end{tabular}}}
\vskip 2ex
\textcolor{lightgray}{\hrule height .5pt}
\vskip 6ex
\Huge{A title in fontsize Huge}
\vskip .4ex
\large{Doe, J. (John)}
\vskip 2ex
\normalsize
\vskip .5ex
\valign{%
    \hsize=\dimexpr.5\linewidth-2\tabcolsep
    \vskip 2ex
    #\vfil\nointerlineskip
    \vskip 1.5ex
    \cr
    \noindent\textls{\itshape\footnotesize KEYWORDS}
    \vskip -1.5ex
    \hbox to\hsize{\color{lightgray}\leaders\hrule height .5pt\hfill}
    \vskip 1.5ex
    \itshape{obituary

    linguist

    typography}\cr
    \noalign{\hfill}
    \noindent\textls{\itshape\footnotesize ABSTRACT}
    \vskip -1.5ex
    \hbox to\hsize{\color{lightgray}\leaders\hrule height .5pt\hfill}
    \vskip 1.5ex

    \small \lipsum[4] \cr
  }\par
  \vskip2ex

  \hbox to\linewidth{\color{lightgray}\leaders\hrule height .5pt\hfill}
\vskip 3ex

\colorbox{palette2}{%
\begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\fboxsep}
\lipsum[1-2]
\end{minipage}%
}
\vskip 5ex
}%----- end measuring
%
\usebox\titlebox

\docparspacing
\begin{multicols*}{3}
\section{Document structure}
\textcolor{red}{The box above has a height of \myheight.}\par
\lipsum[1-3]
\end{multicols*}
\end{document}
```

Note that you have to use the mesuring after `\begin{document}`, but you can measure as many boxes as you like before using any of them.

Comment: Thanks. This will do as a preliminary answer. Did you choose `tcolorbox` because of affinity with the package?

Comment: @1010011010 Yes, I'm the author of this package and so I have a large affinity with it ;-) Also, I used it for similar measuring problems since the package calculates the dimensions anyway.

Comment: @1010011010 Do you just want to *know* the height of your box or do you need the value for further computations? My answer, so far, just displays the dimensions.

Comment: I need the height for further computations, but I can think of a workaround. If you want to include it in your answer, I won't stop you from doing so.

Comment: @1010011010 I've updated my answer with an according variant.

Comment: If nobody mentions a solution where I can declare a box in the preamble (like in my OP) I will accept your answer...

Comment: If you know a solution where I can declare the colorbox in preamble, I'll add in a bounty of 100 rep for effort. :-)

Comment: @1010011010 Maybe, I understood your question wrong. Do you intend to construct the complete box (including measuring) before the document content starts?

Comment: @1010011010 Filling and measuring the box inside the preamble will not work as far as I know. Currently, the box is created and used at the beginning of the document. Since it is the first element of your document, I'm not sure what you want to achieve otherwise?

Comment: The reason why I want to measure the box is because I want to use `flowfram` to mimic a three column layout. The measured heights will determine the way the flow frames are declared on that page and a number of different user manuals explicitly discourage declaring and managing flow frames mid-document. I can confirm this with my own findings, since my flow frames went all over the place in my attempt. This titlebox is not the only box I wish to measure; I also want to include infoboxes on page two and four, which I therefore *have* to measure in preamble, to determine the layout afterwards.

Comment: @1010011010 I've added a third solution which should help with your problem. Additionally, it omits tcolorbox completely which was useful for the first optical one. Nevertheless, the measuring cannot be done in the preamble ... but I think you do not really need to.